# Dynamically change Image -> React component

Tags: reactjs

I have an array `data` which is passed to a reusable component.

```
const data = [
  {
    title: "A",
    source: "facebook",
  },
  {
    title: "B",
    source: "youtube",
  },
  {
    title: "C",
    source: "twitter",
  },
];
```

This is how my re-useable component looks like :

```
import facebook from "../../images/facebook.png";
import youtube from "../../images/youtube.png";
import twitter from "../../images/twitter.png";

function NumberBox({ data }) {
  return (
    <>
      {data.map((item) => (
        <>
          <div className="title">{item.title}</div>
          <img src={item.source} className="image" />
        </>
      ))}
    </>
  );
}
```

I want to dynamically change the img element based on the data from props...like facebook icon, Twitter icon etc. With the code I have written here, i get blank image icon against `{item.source}` all the time but if i replace `{item.source}` with `{facebook}` it works properly. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks.

Comment: `source: twitter` Source must be a reference to a variable( you imported img source), not a string

Answer (score 1):

The string `"facebook"` is not the same as the image `facebook`, which will be resolved by webpack to be the full url to the image. You can do it in two ways, one using a map:

```js
image_map = {
    facebook: facebook,
    ...
}

<img src={image_map[data.source}]>
```

Other way is to place the url in data:

```js
import facebook from '../images/facebook.png'

data = [
   title: 'facebook', 
   image: facebook // Notice: no quotes
]
```

Answer (score 1):

`source: twitter` Source must be a reference to a variable( you imported img source), not a string

```
const data = [
    {
       title: 'A'
       source: facebook // facebook but not 'facebook'
    },

    {
       title: 'B'
        source: youtube
    },

    {
      title: 'C'        
      source: twitter
    }
];
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code `item.source` is a string (like `'facebook'`), and has no relation with the image imported `import facebook from '../../images/facebook.png';`

The easy and clean way is setting the image in `data`, by importing:

```js
import facebook from '../../images/facebook.png';

const data = [
    {
       title: 'A',
       source: 'facebook',
       image: facebook,

    },
```

... or usign a public url:

```js
const data = [
    {
       title: 'A',
       source: 'facebook',
       image: 'https://domain/public-url-to-image.jpg',

    },
```

and later:

```js
<img src={data.image} />
```

Answer (score 0):

`item.source` is a string not a source path to a file. To resolve this issue you can check which `item.source` is and use the source from the import statement like following:

```
function NumberBox({ data }) {
  return (
    <>
      {data.map((item) => (
        <>
          <div className="title">{item.title}</div>
          {item.source === 'facebook' && <img src={facebook} className="image" />}
          {item.source === 'twitter' && <img src={twitter} className="image" />}
          {item.source === 'youtube' && <img src={youtube} className="image" />}
        </>
      ))}
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: This would be a mess to maintain if there where more images

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing a string which happens to be "facebook", "youtube" or "twitter" it is not an image file. If you use the imported image which name is "twitter" then it will show the image. You have to update your data array to reference the image variable. Remove the quote marks and it should work. Example how to use with links. Your data should be

```
const data = [
  {
    title: "A",
    source: facebook,
  },
  {
    title: "B",
    source: youtube,
  },
  {
    title: "C",
    source: twitter,
  },
];
```

https://codepen.io/shnigi/pen/MWvpMeE